# jquery.mobile "tap" fired "focus" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile

There's a problem with the event "tap" into jquery.mobile. When a "tap" on the item, then the item is hidden, it triggers the event "focus" on the INPUT field which is located under the item. 
How can I make so that the focus event does not fired?
Here is a small sample code.

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .drop {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 100;
      padding: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .drop .holder {
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 10px 10px 3px;
      margin: 0 24px -2px;
      background: #1c365b;
    }
    a {font-size: 24px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="#" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="input 1">
    <input type="text" name="input 2">
    <input type="text" name="input 3">
  </form>
  <div class="drop">
    <div class="holder">
      <a>Link 1</a><br>
      <a>Link 2</a><br>
      <a>Link 3</a><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="console"></div>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      var console = $('#console');
      $('.drop').find('a').unbind('tap').bind('tap', function (e) {
        console.append(' tap on drop menu');
        $('.drop').hide();
        return false;
      });
      $('#form').find('input').unbind('focus').bind('focus', function (e) {
        console.append(' focus on ' + $(e.target).attr('name'));
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

After hidden drop you get:

```
<div id="console">tap on drop menu focus on input 2</div>
```

stopImmediatePropagation() method does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Using your exact code in JSFiddle I don't get the problem you are getting.
I have tried this in a desktop browser and on my S3 in the chrome browser.

The overlaid div disappears and fires the tap event but the focus event does not fire until you then select one of the input boxes after the overlay is gone.

http://jsfiddle.net/U9bYR/

The only code I changed was remove the unnecessary methods in your event code.

```
$(function () {
  var console = $('#console');
  $('.drop').bind('tap', function (e) {
    console.append(' tap on drop menu');
    $('.drop').hide();
    return false;
  });
$('#form').find("input").bind('focus', function (e) {
    console.append(' focus on ' + $(e.target).attr('name'));
  });
});
```

Comment: In chrome browser everything seems good. I can reproduce it on "Mobile Safari" and "Opera Mobi". I'm using phonegap in my project, which uses "Safari" browser.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is that I need to replace the tap event(provided jquery.mobile) on the click event(provided jquery).

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly same issue, I was not able to find good solution to that.

I guess it is a issue with Mobile Safari, but you are the first one I found who has the same issue as me.

Temporary solution is: **disable all fields that you suppose are hidden under button you are about to click.**

In Sencha it looks like this:

```
disableFields: function() {
    this.enableFieldsFunc(); //lets make sure all fields were switched back to default values
    this.disableAllFields();  //and then disable them
},
disableAllFields: function() {
    fields = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('field');
    for(var i = 0; i<fields.length; i++) {
        var field = fields[i];
        if(field.getComponent() && field.getComponent().input && field.getComponent().input.dom && field.getComponent().input.dom) {
            field.wasDisabledBefore = field.getComponent().input.dom.disabled;
            field.getComponent().input.dom.disabled = true;
        }
    }
},
enableFields: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', this.enableFieldsFunc, this).delay(100);
},
enableFieldsFunc: function() {
    fields = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('field');
    for(var i = 0; i<fields.length; i++) {
        var field = fields[i];
        var disabled = field.wasDisabledBefore;
        if(typeof disabled != 'undefined') {
            field.getComponent().input.dom.disabled = disabled;
        }
    }
}
```

And on **pressed** and **released** events I am calling *disableFields* and *enableFields*